# hset() for redis in python

Tags: python, redis, hashset

I have next question:

I use the `hset()` procedure for Redis Server in python. This procedure is described [here](http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.hset).

ok, now I couldn't understand the parameter `value`... From one hand it should be a number 0 or 1, anyway I could use also other numbers for this parameter (and I also find examples in net with other values). For example I define next def:

```
    def setHashKeyValue(key, value, number):
        assert (key != None), "Please, get a key"
        #assert (number == 0 or number ==1), "Please enter 0 or 1"
        redis_server.hset(key, value, number);
```

And got right output with the next parameters:

```
setHashKeyValue('5', 'test ok for key 5', 1)
setHashKeyValue('6', 'test ok for key 6', 1)
```

On the other hand, I would like to define some loop for time measuring, so I define next def:

```
def loopKeyValues(number):
    timeUse = []
    for x in range(number):
        start = time.time()
        setHashKeyValue(x, x**2, 1)
        end = time. time()
        timeUse.append(end-start)
    plt.plot(timeUse)
    plt.ylabel("time")
    plt.show()
    return timeUse;
```

and

```
print loopKeyValues(1000)
```

This function return me an error message for HashValue:

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

When I use `set()`-def instead of `hset()`, the program return me a nice time plot. What could be a problem here and what means the parameter `value`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value parameter is just the key of your hash object entry.

Hash objects are like Python dictionaries. They provide associative arrays. When you write:

```
redis_server.hset(key, value, number)
```

it means the hash object "key" will be added/set with an entry "value"/"number". In Python, you would write:

```
key[value] = number
```

You got an error because in Redis the objects are typed. Once you have stored a string at a given key, Redis cannot consider anymore this object is a hash object: so the operations associated to a hash object will not work for this key.

In other words, if you have:

```
SET 10 100
```

then you cannot do:

```
HSET 10 100 1
```

However you could do:

```
DEL 10
HSET 10 100 1
```

I would suggest to use the redis-cli program to experiment with Redis before using Python scripts.

Comment: thsank you very much, now is everything clear. I just define my parameters in the wrong order